# Bi-dimensional Fast Fourier Transformation Problem

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, 2d, fft

I am new to image processing and in need of some help here. I refer to Fig.10 of the paper by Z. Yang, M. Krishnamurthy and I. P. Brown, "Electromagnetic and vibrational characteristic of IPM over full torque-speed range" [image: Fig10]

According to the authors, a 2d-FFT was performed to change the figure on the left to that on the right. However, it did not work out for me. Applied fft2(Matlab) to [image: Pic1] and got this [image: Pic2].

Please tell me what am I missing.

Thank you in advance.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the authors used artistic license to cut off the coefficients below some chosen intensity threshold close to zero, and not color them at all. This helps presentation if the order of magnitude of the coefficients is close to the numeric noise floor, i.e. in a clean data set.

Exclude the DC value in your upper left from the dynamic range (color bar range) calculations. It tends to be the largest value and not central to the purpose of the plot.

To account for the different position of your spectral peaks, consider the differences in your data set which has a higher base frequency along both axis (assuming the units are the same.)

Another difference are the axis meanings. The paper plots frequencies as harmonics to some base frequency.